# What's the cheapest place I can get a high-rise view in New York City?

Tags: budget, accommodation, new-york-city

I'm  spending a night in New York City on the way to DC this May.

Growing up in the suburbs, I've always wanted to get a view like this from my hotel room (the church is irrelevant I just liked the photo):

[image]

I've never been to New York (well, I drove through once) and so I don't know which neighborhoods to look at or anything. Being close to the airport would be nice (don't know which one I'm flying to yet) but that's just an extra.

However, I'm also on a college budget.

**So, where is the cheapest place to stay I can find a view like this?** I know this won't be a $50 view, but it's worth it to me. Say, $100-150.

Comment: It is extremely unlikely that you ever will.  The Rooms with a view usually are charged premium and given the average hotel prices in Manhattan $100-$150 with a view is a pipe dream.

Comment: @Karlson a friend of mine is staying in a midtown high-rise hotel for $165 a night.  But it's now February; he indicated that he can't afford to stay in this hotel at other times of the year, by which I infer that prices will be significantly higher in May.

Comment: @phoog There are a few times a year when there are sales on room prices.  There was a time I stayed in Marriott Marquee for about $150/night (no view) but still.  Usually it's during slow times like now or right after Thanksgiving.

Comment: @Karlson is the only place to get views like this Manhattan?

Comment: @Azor-Ahai Most other locations don't need hotels with high floor count.  You can try Jersey City but view like this would be a Manhattan specific.

Comment: @Karlson I have been to New Jersey, not something I'd like to do again... What price range am I looking at for this sorry of thing? $200 says Google, does that seem right?

Comment: @Azor-Ahai seems fairly reasonable.  Views may cost extra.

Comment: Close voters: Would it be more helpful to ask which neighborhood has the cheapest hotels with this sort of view?

Comment: @Azor-Ahai Add as much detail you think is relevant, to narrow the scope of the question down to something answerable.

Comment: @JoErNanO I'm confused, wouldn't adding more detail bring it closer to a travel-agent question? "I want a hotel in Manhattan in on May 13, can you tell me the cheapest one?"